# How to write a regex in lex that negates the whitespaces

Tags: regex, lex

I am new to Lex (Flex) and I am solving a question that asks me to write a lex program that copies a file, replacing each non-empty sequence of whitespace by a single blank.
Here is what I have tried

```
%{
    FILE *rp,*wp;
    /*Read pointer and write pointer*/
%}

delim   [ \t\n]
ws      {delim}+
nows    [^{ws}]
%%
{nows}  {fprintf(wp,"%s",yytext);}
{ws}    {fprintf(wp,"%c",' ');}
%%
int yywrap(){}

int  main(int argc,char** argv){
    rp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    wp=fopen(argv[2],"w+");
    yyin=rp;
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(wp);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that using caret(^) character I would match any character other than the whitespaces but instead, it is removing **w** and **s** from the input.
So does anyone know how can I negate the whitespaces? Also, any other approach to solve the problem is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whitespace negation is `\S`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn could you please be a little more detailed as changing 
**nows [^{ws}]** to **nows [\S]** does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from the book on compilers by Alfred V Aho and Jeffrey D Ullman here is a solution to the above problem.
The ws can be defined as `ws [\t \n]+` and nows can be defined as `nows .`.
Even though `.` is used to match all characters but since `ws` will be written first, therefore, lex will match this rule when it sees a whitespace character.
Therefore the complete code becomes

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    FILE *rp,*wp;
    /*Read pointer and write pointer*/
%}

ws      [\t \n]+
nows    .
%%
{nows}  {fprintf(wp,"%s",yytext);}
{ws}    {fprintf(wp," ");}
%%
int yywrap(){}

int  main(int argc,char** argv){
    rp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    wp=fopen(argv[2],"w");
    yyin=rp;
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(wp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an input and output file demonstrating the working of the program
input.txt

```
This is     a test  file   for 
the 
    program copy.l This file must be properly
formatted.
Here   we are trying to
    
        write     some gibberish   
    Also here is   some line.
```

And here is its output
output.txt

```
This is a test file for the program copy.l This file must be properly formatted. Here we are trying to write some gibberish Also here is some line.
```